# Extracting complete dataframe from Hmisc package in R

Tags: r, hmisc

I've used aregImpute to impute the missing values then i used impute.transcan function trying to get complete dataset using the following code.

```
impute_arg <- aregImpute(~ age + job + marital + education + default +
balance + housing + loan + contact + day + month + duration + campaign +
pdays + previous + poutcome + y , data = mov.miss, n.impute = 10 , nk =0)


imputed <- impute.transcan(impute_arg, imputation=1, data=mov.miss, list.out=TRUE, pr=FALSE, check=FALSE)
y <- completed[names(imputed)]
```

and when i used str(y) it already gives me a dataframe but with **NAs** as it is not imputed before, My question is how to get complete dataset without NAs after imputation?

```
str(y)
'data.frame':   4521 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ age      : int  30 NA 35 30 NA 35 36 39 41 43 ...
 $ job      : Factor w/ 12 levels "admin.","blue-collar",..: 11 8 5 5 2 5 7 10 3 8 ...
 $ marital  : Factor w/ 3 levels "divorced","married",..: 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ education: Factor w/ 4 levels "primary","secondary",..: 1 2 3 3 2 3 NA 2 3 1 ...
 $ default  : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 NA 1 1 1 ...
 $ balance  : int  NA 4789 1350 1476 0 747 307 147 NA -88 ...
 $ housing  : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": NA 2 2 2 NA 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ loan     : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 2 1 2 NA 1 1 NA 1 2 ...
 $ contact  : Factor w/ 3 levels "cellular","telephone",..: 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 NA 1 ...
 $ day      : int  19 NA 16 3 5 23 14 6 14 NA ...
 $ month    : Factor w/ 12 levels "apr","aug","dec",..: 11 9 1 7 9 4 NA 9 9 1 ...
 $ duration : int  79 220 185 199 226 141 341 151 57 313 ...
 $ campaign : int  1 1 1 4 1 2 1 2 2 NA ...
 $ pdays    : int  -1 339 330 NA -1 176 330 -1 -1 NA ...
 $ previous : int  0 4 NA 0 NA 3 2 0 0 2 ...
 $ poutcome : Factor w/ 4 levels "failure","other",..: 4 1 1 4 4 1 2 4 4 1 ...
 $ y        : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code myself, and it works just fine, except for the last line:

`y <- completed[names(imputed)]`

I believe there's a type in the above line. Plus, you do not even need the `completed` function.

Besides, if you want to get a data.frame from the `impute.transcan` function, then wrap it with `as.data.frame`:

```
imputed <- as.data.frame(impute.transcan(impute_arg, imputation=1, data=mov.miss, list.out=TRUE, pr=FALSE, check=FALSE))
```

Moreover, if you need to test your missing data pattern, you can also use the `md.pattern` function provided by the `mice` package.

Comment: Really thanks for your precious time and for your answer, but it still not working ,i need to have a dataset like (y) .but when i tried your code it give me a data with a class type that couldn't do any manipulation on it(like classification). so do you have another solution.

Comment: Please test it with this code: `impute_arg <- aregImpute(~ age + job + marital + education + default +
balance + housing + loan + contact + day + month + duration + campaign +
pdays + previous + poutcome + y , data = mov.miss, n.impute = 2 , nk =0)`
Make sure it finishes the execution. Then use the code I provided ( `imputed <- as.data.frame(impute.transcan(impute_arg, imputation=1, data=mov.miss, list.out=TRUE, pr=FALSE, check=FALSE))
`) to extract the first imputed dataset as a data frame.

Comment: @MennatallahIbrahim please then accept and upvote the answer

Comment: I already accept it . i'm trying to upvote it but it gives me a message that i'm with less than 15 reputation.